# Probability of sum over a window of binary vector

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binary

I have a vector of one's and zero's of length n with a probability p of observing a one and 1-p of observing a zero. I slide a (overlapping) window of size $k$ across this vector and take the sum (which can take values $0\dots k$). What is the probability of observing a particular sum?

My specific problem uses $n=1000000$, $p=0.995$, $k=3$ and this is what I'm mostly interested in, however a general solution would be nice.

I've enumerated the different possibilities that give rise to each sum for $k=3$, i.e. $$p^3 + (2p+1-p)*3 + (p+2(1-p))*3 + (1-p)^3 = 1$$ but does the fact that the sliding windows are overlapping change the probabilities?

Comment: Is $n$ the length of your tape?  Is the sum the total visible within the window?

Comment: To be precise, I slide the window though the whole vector (or "tape") and then want the proportion of windows which have a sum of 0,1,2,3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your calculation
$$p^3 + (2p+1-p)^3 + (p+2(1-p))^3 + (1-p)^3$$
should be instead
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \Pr[\mbox{sum}=i]=\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} \,p^i (1-p)^{k-i}= p^3 + 3p^2(1-p) +3p(1-p)^2 + (1-p)^3$$

Comment: Making it simply the [Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). This may not work, though, because the windows are not independent. For instance, you can't go from 111 to 000; you can only enter 111 again or 110.

Comment: Though I may be wrong, that is how I understood the OP's question. I don't think he really means to keep track of the sums when he slides the window. He just slides the window to a random position and calculates the sum.

Comment: @Hoda I've corrected my probability calculation, now it sums up to one like your formal suggestion. To be precise, slide the window throughout the whole vector and then need to calculate the prob of a sum of 0,1,2,3.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your window shows $xyz$.  The follow matrix is your probability for shifting to $yzw$:

$$
\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    & 000 & 001 & 010 & 011 & 100 & 101 & 110 & 111 \\ \hline
000 & 1-p &   p &     &     &     &     &     &     \\ \hline
001 &     &     & 1-p &   p &     &     &     &     \\ \hline
010 &     &     &     &     & 1-p &   p &     &     \\ \hline
011 &     &     &     &     &     &     & 1-p &   p \\ \hline
100 & 1-p &   p &     &     &     &     &     &     \\ \hline
101 &     &     & 1-p &   p &     &     &     &     \\ \hline
110 &     &     &     &     & 1-p &   p &     &     \\ \hline
111 &     &     &     &     &     &     & 1-p &   p \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Suppose we are interested in a target $T=2$.  Then we can simplify the table to:

$$
\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
    & 000 & 001 & 010 & 100 & 111 & T=2 \\ \hline
000 & 1-p &   p &     &     &     &     \\ \hline
001 &     &     & 1-p &     &     & p   \\ \hline
010 &     &     &     & 1-p &     & p   \\ \hline
100 & 1-p &   p &     &     &     &     \\ \hline
111 &     &     &     &     &   p & 1-p \\ \hline
T=2 &     &     &     &     &     & 1   \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

With your problem, $p = 0.995$, so the transition matrix becomes:

$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
0.005 & 0.995 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0  & .005 & 0  & 0  & 0.995 \\ 
 0 & 0  & 0  & .005 & 0  & 0.995 \\ 
.005 &0.995 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  \\ 
 0 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0.995 & .005 \\ 
 0 & 0  & 0  & 0  & 0  & 1   \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Your initial probability of being in a given window state is:
$$V = \begin{bmatrix} 1/8 & 1/8 & 1/8 & 1/8 & 1/8 & 3/8 \end{bmatrix}$$

After the initial state, which gives  you 3 tape entries, you see $n - 3$ more, so your final probability is:
$$VM^{n-3}$$

For n being a million, your probability will be so close to 100% that there is really no point in trying to calculate it...

But for something small, like $n = 10$, you can see:

$$VM^7 = \begin{bmatrix} 
7.98 \cdot 10^{-13} & 
1.58 \cdot 10^{-10} &
3.48 \cdot 10^{-12} &
1.94 \cdot 10^{-12} &
0.12 &
0.87
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So for a shorter $n=10$ tape, you have a 87% chance of having passed through a state with a sum $T=2$.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. What I was looking for was "how many states of sum T=2 can I expect in my tape", rather than "what is the chance of passing through a state with sum T=2 in my tape". Sorry for the confusion.